# Windows 7 VBScript Choosing Window by Title

Tags: windows, windows-7, vbscript

So it seems as though the following bit of code works with Windows XP, but does NOT work with Windows 7:

```
Dim objFileSys

Set objFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objShell.AppActivate("Query Express") Then 
Else
    objShell.run chr(34) & "I:\SQL-Queries\QueryExpress\QueryExpress.exe" & chr(34),1,False
End If
```

Basically, it checks to see if the window is already open.  If it is NOT open, it opens it.

Pretty simple, eh?  Well, this bit of code does not work as scripted in Windows 7.  Can someone clue me in as to how to update it to work?

Thanks!

Comment: So how does it fail? And have you tried with some other target windows? And is anything running as admin?

Comment: Well, this script should detect whether or not I have a window open with the title "Query Express".  I do have this window open, but it still opens another instance of Query Express.  No errors, but it SHOULD do nothing since I already have it open.

Comment: I actually had a bunch of AppActivate commands flying around in a previous test, but it never worked at all, so I tried to simplify it.  Still, not working... :(

Comment: Does it work with a Notepad window?

Comment: Interesting...  It does work with Notepad!  Why does it not work with ALL windows?

Comment: Are any of the processes running elevated?

Comment: Not that I know of.  I am an admin on this machine and everything is being execute via an HTA file that I have crafted.